# Мультиязычность посредство JSON. Вопрос безопасности

Tags: php, json, безопасность

Срочно и внезапно надо было сделать мультиязычность небольшого PHP-проекта. Первое что пришло в голову: хранить для каждого языка отдельный JSON - файл и посредством PHP\JS открывать его чтобы считывать\записывать (при редактировании) информацию. 
Сейчас вот задумался: может ли любой желающий посредством JavaScript считать прямо со страницы этот файл и внести в него изменения?

Comment: Вот вам ядрена бомба http://php.net/manual/ru/book.intl.php

Answer (score 4):

Обычно локализация делается на уровне сервера, где нужный файл подключается во время работы и строка выводится в нужном вам языке. Так как перевод строк, используемых в приложении часто статичен, используются статические файлы. Если же есть необходимость то используется БД для более гибкого использования языковых настроек и значений.
Ввести какие-либо данные и изменить их НА СЕРВЕРЕ никто не сможет так как JavaScript - это клиентский язык, и с помощью него получится обрабатывать в большинстве своём данные уже на машине клиента. (Я не учитываю отсылаемые запросы типа POST через прокси которые могут что-либо изменить на сервере)